# Handle 0/0 division in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Need help modify syntax to handle if both = 0, then return 0 else divide AJ10/AA10.

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(AJ10),IF(ISBLANK(AA10),"",0)),AJ10/AA10)
```

Thanks

Comment: `=IF(AND(AJ10=0, AA10=0),0,AJ10/AA10)`

Comment: Look at the `IFERROR()` formula - you don't need to explicitly test the values going into your base formula for all possible error conditions, you can instead wrap the formula in `IFERROR(YourFormula,value_if_error)` and state what should be returned in the case of any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(OR(AJ10="",AA10="",AA10=0),"",AJ10/AA10)
```

Basically, this is an `IF` statement which asks: if AJ10 is blank, or AA10 is blank, or the denominator (AA10) is zero, place a blank, otherwise, place AJ10 divided by AA10.

Note that `=""` is a shortcut for `ISBLANK`.

Answer (score 1):

You really only need to worry if AA10 is 0:

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(AJ10),ISBLANK(AA10)),"",if(AA10=0,0,AJ10/AA10))
```

Comment: `=IF(AA10=0,0,AJ10/AA10)`? Or if OP really must test *both*, then `=IF(AND(AJ10=0, AA10=0),0,AJ10/AA10)`?

Comment: @DavidZemens I may have understood it differently, I was thinking that OP wanted to keep if either is blank then result is blank, else deal with the divide by 0 error.  But I may be mistaken.